# Telegram bot: GetUpdates Conflict

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I have created the test Telegram bot console app using sample from this link
https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples

There is my main

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    Bot = new TelegramBotClient(Configuration.BotToken);
    var me = await Bot.GetMeAsync();
    Console.Title = me.Username;

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // StartReceiving does not block the caller thread. Receiving is done on the ThreadPool.
    Console.WriteLine($"Bot.Timeout= {Bot.Timeout}");

    //Bot.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);
    Bot.StartReceiving(
        new DefaultUpdateHandler(HandleUpdateAsync, HandleErrorAsync),
        cts.Token
    );

    Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");

    Console.ReadLine();

    // Send cancellation request to stop bot
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

I run it on Windows 10 - it works fine.
But when I run it on the Windows 7 machine I receive the exception:

> Bot.Timeout= 00:01:40 Start listening for @my123_bot HandleErrorAsync
>   Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Conflict: terminat ed by
>   other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is
>   running    at
>   Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.d__54`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)    at
>   Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClientPollingExtensions.<ReceiveAsync>d__3.MoveNex
>   t() HandleErrorAsync Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException:
>   Conflict: terminat ed by other getUpdates request; make sure that only
>   one bot instance is running    at
>   Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.<MakeRequestAsync>d__54`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)    at
>   Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClientPollingExtensions.d__3.MoveNex
>   t()

What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: ": terminat ed by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running" There are multiple request to the same `getUpdates()`. Are you sure the bot is not running on the W10 machine, or maybe hidden in the background?

Comment: It may be the reason: if I run 2 bots on 2 machines? @ years ago I run my old bot on 3 machines and they worked

Comment: Yea, you can't / shouldn't run a manual bot that calls `getUpdates()` on multiple instances. Or, you should create a real solid solution with [web-hooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)

Comment: Maybe those old bots were perfectly timed so they never did the same request? If you can ensure that there will always be x seconds between the calls, and you'll never tell telegram you've saw a message that another bot did not yet saw, it should work. But that's just **not** the way to go ;)

Comment: Ok, it seems the web-hooks may be the solution. Create answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>As described in the comments;</sup>

> : terminat ed by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

Indicates that `getUpdates()` is being called at the same time.

To prevent this, either stop the other bots, or create a bot that will receive a [web-hook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) *HTTP POST* request on update.

You should ensure that each message is handled by the bot(s) before you tell Telegram the message has been seen by the  [`getUpdate()` offset](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) param.

Answer (score 1):

> make sure that only one bot instance is running

I was able to solve this problem by revoking and updating bot token. This worked because I think it stopped all the bot instances that were using the old token.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with rebooting my PC. I guess problem appears because the processes we cant see and rebooting just stops them down

Comment: Your answer's grammar logic seems to be a bit confusing.